# Why Malloc Is Not Always Needed With Pointers to Char?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Why the following code works:

```
char *p;

p="hello";

printf("%s\n",p);
```

While this one doesn't:

```
char *p;

strcpy(p,"hello");

printf("%s\n",p);
```

I know that adding p=malloc(4); on the second example would make the code work, but that is exactly my question. Why malloc is needed in the second example but not in the first?

I looked for similar questions on SO but none answer this exactly.

Comment: Did you just edit this in the 5 minute grace period? I swear it said `scanf` originally not `strcpy`, which changes the answer somewhat.

Comment: Yes I figured strcpy would make it easier to understand the question, and I don't think it changes the answer. Does it?

Comment: This a basic question. A bit of research should have given you the answer fairly quickly.

Comment: I looked for similar stuff in SO, but couldn't find an exact answer.

Comment: I'd recommend `strdup` for the `strcpy` example, because it allocates sufficient memory *and* copies in one. Not using `scanf("%2", p)` also has the result that the size of the string is known, because the size of `"hello"` is fixed.

Comment: @awoodland There is no function called strdup in the C language, so I wouldn't recommend it. Stick to standard functions unless you have no other choise.

Comment: @Lundin - you're right, sorry I assumed it was a C99 thing. That doesn't change that I'd started writing about `scanf("%s"` and unknown length input before the edit changed it to `strcpy` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` is a pointer. You need to make it point to *something*. In the first case,

```
 p = "hello";
```

makes `p` point to that string literal which is located somewhere in your program's memory at runtime.

In your second case, you didn't make `p` point to anything, so doing anything that looks at where `p` points to is invalid.

```
p = malloc(some_size);
```

makes `p` point to a piece of (uninitialized) memory that can hold `some_size` chars. If you reserved enough, you can then do things like `strcpy(p, "hello")` because `p` does point to a valid memory area, so copying into the memory pointed-to by `p` is ok. Note that `some_size` must be at least as big as what you want to copy into it, including the `'\0'` string terminator.

Note that doing:

```
p = "hello";
strcpy(p, "bye");
```

would be invalid because `"hello"` can be stored as in a read-only memory, so you can't overwrite it.

Comment: You say "If you reserved enough memory, you can then do things like strcpy(p, "hello")". Wouldn't 4 bytes of memory for p be enough to store any string there, since p will always be just a pointer to the first char?

Comment: @DanielScocco `p` points to the memory `strcpy` is copying `"hello"` into. It has to be at least 6 bytes big (1 for each character of `hello` and one for the NULL terminator).

Comment: It works with just 4 bytes allocated here. Maybe it's a lucky coincidence.

Comment: @DanielScocco: clarified a bit. You reserve memory, and store the _address_ of that memory into `p`. The size of `p` itself depends on the architecture (4 or 8 bytes are common these days), but it is not relevant to the size of the memory area that `p` _points to_.

Comment: @DanielScocco: "it works" is one of the many symptoms of undefined behavior. "it works" doesn't mean "it's right". Try reserving 4 bytes, and copying a _very_ long string (say 256 chars) and see if it still "works".

Comment: @DanielScocco - I'd say it's an *un* lucky coincidence when undefined behaviour slips through unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

`"hello"` is a string literal and will live in part of your output program. The memory is allocated by the compiler, at compile time, *in the same place as the actual code*<sup>*</sup>

That is to say that the type of `"hello"` will be `const char[6]`, which is converted automatically into `char *`. (Using `const char*` instead of `char*` for string literals is a good habit to get into though)

In the second case `p` is uninitalised when you call `strcpy`, thus the result is undefined. `p=malloc(4);` **is not** sufficient to fix this either, the string "hello" is made of *6* characters  -- 5 from the word hello itself plus `'\0'` to terminate the string.

<sup>*</sup> Actually on modern systems that's not quite true, it's *near* the same place as the code.

Answer (score 0):

`p="hello";` assigns the address of the string literal "hello" to `p`, while `scanf` requires a place to put the scanned input, so you need to allocate some memory (static, dynamic or automatic) for it.

Comment: But with p="hello" the string literal must be stored somewhere, so the program takes care of allocating/desalocating that automatically? Also, how to allocate static, dynamic and automatic memory for p if you want to use scanf or strcpy? I only know using malloc, which I believe is dynamic allocation right?

Comment: @DanielScocco yes string literals are often stored in the binary program file itself in the static data section. Dynamic allocation is `malloc`, automatic memory is just on the stack, like `char p[size];` where `size` is an integer, and static memory would just be `static int whatever;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy(p,"hello");
```

For string literal `hello` to be **copied**, p must point to a valid memory location which in this case isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Because the value that `p` has is going to be random and any attempts to copy the string there will result in a crash. By using malloc you ensure that the value of `p` will be ok for a copy to occur (as long as the buffer is big enough)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that in situations like this, a picture comes in handy.

Let's combine your two snippets above:

```
char *p = "Hello";
char *q;

strcpy(q, "goodbye");
printf("p = %s, q = %s\n", p, q);
```

Here's a hypothetical memory map showing the relationships between `p`, `q`, and the strings `"Hello"` and `"goodbye"`:

```
Item        Address           0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----        -------           ----  ----  ----  ----
  "Hello"   0x00080000        'H'   'e'   'l'   'l'
            0x00080004        'o'   0x00  0x??  0x??
"goodbye"   0x00080008        'g'   'o'   'o'   'd'
            0x0008000C        'b'   'y'   'e'   0x00
            ...
        p   0x01010000        0x00  0x08  0x00  0x00
        q   0x01010004        0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
```

`"Hello"` and `"goodbye"` are string literals, which are arrays of `char` (`const char` in C++), stored in such a way that they are active over the lifetime of the program.  The literal `"Hello"` is stored beginning at address 0x00080000, and the literal "goodbye" is stored beginning at address 0x00080008.

`p` and `q` are pointers to `char` with `auto` extent, meaning that they only exist for the lifetime of the block in which they are declared.  In this case, they are located at addresses 0x01010000 and 0x01010004, respectively (we're assuming 32-bit pointers in this example).

When you write `char *p = "Hello";`, the array expression `"Hello"` is converted to a pointer expression whose value is the location of the first element of the array, and that pointer value is copied to `p`, as seen in the memory map above.

When you write `char *q;`, the initial value of `q` is indeterminate<sup>1</sup> as indicated by the `0x??` byte values.  That value may or may not correspond to a writable address; odds are that it doesn't.  So basically, when you write `strcpy(q, "goodbye");`, you're attempting to copy the contents of the `"goodbye"` string literal to a random location in memory.  More often than not, that's going to lead to a runtime error.

If you allocate a buffer for the string, the buffer must be long enough to store the entire string plus the 0 terminator; allocating just 4 bytes isn't enough, because then your string will spill over into memory you don't "own", potentially clobbering something important (technically, the behavior is undefined, meaning anything can happen).  IOW, you don't have to allocate memory for the pointer (that's already done when you declare the pointer), you have to allocate memory for the thing being pointed to.

If we change our code snippet to something like

```
char *p = "Hello";
char *q;

q = malloc(10);
strcpy(q, "goodbye");
printf("p = %s, q = %s\n", p, q);
```

then our memory map will look something like this:

```
Item        Address           0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----        -------           ----  ----  ----  ----
  "Hello"   0x00080000        'H'   'e'   'l'   'l'
            0x00080004        'o'   0x00  0x??  0x??
"goodbye"   0x00080008        'g'   'o'   'o'   'd'
            0x0008000C        'b'   'y'   'e'   0x00
            ...
        p   0x01010000        0x00  0x08  0x00  0x00
        q   0x01010004        0x40  0x00  0x00  0x00
            ...
<dynamic>   0x40000000        'g'   'o'   'o'   'd'
            0x40000004        'b'   'y'   'e'   0x00
            0x40000008        0x??  0x??
```

In this case, `malloc` sets aside 10 bytes of memory starting at 0x40000000, and copies that address to `q`.  The call to `strcpy` then copies the contents of the string literal "goodbye" to that location.

---

<sup>1</sup>If `q` had been declared as `static` or at file scope (outside of any function) , then it would have been initialized to 0 (0x00000000).